# Make new/update a Schedule for laravel command from controller? Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have an api controller for receiving a message called `message()`

Is it possible to schedule a command inside the `message()`controller using the scheduler? say i want to schedule a command to run 1 hour from when `message()` got accessed

Thank You.

Comment: I don't think the scheduler is appropriate here. It looks like [delayed job dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) might be more appropriate

Comment: @apokryfos So i've told. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$schedule->command(SendEmailsCommand::class, ['Taylor', '--force'])->daily();
```

The array is of addition command-line arguments that should be provided to the command when it is invoked. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands).

I think that [queuing a job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) might be more appropriate though depending on what the command is.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route()->named('message')) {
        Message::dispatch($message)
                ->delay(now()->addMinutes(60));
    }

}
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need. Thank you. Though I need to do more research to do queing, thx anyway.